# Sending device unique token to the push notifications provider

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, token

My push notifications provider wants me to send a device-unique token to the server, which is not possible, as I figured out after hours of searching (neither with keychain nor identifierForVendor etc). 
So atm server stores tons of inactive tokens (after app is reinstalled, token is being refreshed). What is the workaround in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the notification APN token to the server, the server can cull them when they attempt to use them.

The Apple Push Notification server will let them know the token is invalid.